# How to use ffmpeg to batch split and batch convert in d:/ drive and save output file in e:/ drive?

Tags: ffmpeg

i am trying to use ffmpeg where i have a folder in (d:/ ) drive which contains nearly 100 videos as (*.mp4) but i need specific time from (22 sec to 1 min 13 sec ) of all videos and need to save the converted file in (*.wav) using ffmpeg file in (e:/) drive songs folder and delete the converted and regularly check for any file in (d:/) drive.

After research i have found a code to split as

```
echo off
mkdir new_folder
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -b:a 192k -vn -ss 0:00:22 -t 0:01:13  "new_folder\%%~na.wav" 
pause
```

Comment: And what happened when you run that script?

Comment: this did the rest of cutting the video and saving in another folder location but couldnot delete the file in the raw data folder and scan for any new file